# Interstitial AdMob mediation on Android

Tags: android, admob, chartboost, inmobi, adcolony

I'm implementing mediation of **Interstitial Ads** through **AdMob** on Android. I would like to integrate 4 additional ad networks:

InMobi, AdColony, Chartboost, and Applovin.

As far as I understood by reading the official documentation on each website, enabling interstitial ad mediation is as easy as:

- Creating an account on each of the ad networks above
- Integrating the SDK and the adapter for AdMob
- Activating mediation for each of the networks above through the AdMob website
- Initializing/configuring the SDKs before creating an AdRequest

Here's my code for the initialization of the SDKs:

```
                InMobiSdk.init(adContext, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                InMobiSdk.setGender(InMobiSdk.Gender.MALE);
                InMobiSdk.setYearOfBirth(1993);

                AppLovinSdk.initializeSdk(adContext);

                AdColony.configure((Activity) adContext, "version:2.3.0,store:google", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxx");

                Chartboost.startWithAppId((Activity) adContext, "xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
                Chartboost.onCreate((Activity) adContext);
```

After doing that I create the AdRequest:

```
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(adContext);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxxxxxx");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setGender(AdRequest.GENDER_MALE)
                .setBirthday(new GregorianCalendar(1993, 1, 1).getTime())
                .build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Unfortunately, I can't see any interstitial other than the ones provided by Google and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried to find some information in the debug logs but I didn't find anything useful.

On the other hand, mediation with banner ads is working like a charm.

Is there any additional implementation step that I should do to get ad mediation work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?
You intialized inmobi, cb, applovin and adcolony. After that you are creating admob interstitial and loading its request. As expected, google admob interstitial showed up....

Comment: According to AdMob documentation, if mediation is configured in the admin console, AdMob SDK should automatically show, if available, the ad  of the network with the highest eCPM. The same mechanism is currently working for us on iOS.

Comment: hope you added adapters...did you enable test mode for all ad networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation and digging, I figured it out.

In order for the mediation to work, you need to create the appropriate proguard (obfuscation tool available by default in Android Studio) rules.

This is needed in order to allow the AdMob SDK to find your adapter class (the obfuscation process renames all classes, except those for which there's a proguard rule) and instantiate it.

Hope it will help other developers who have been struggling with this issue.

Comment: can you please prodvide progruard rule? @pAkY88

Answer (score -1):

You will also need to include the libraries for the ad network that intend to include.
So in total you need:

- AdMob library
- Zero or more of

  - Additional Ad Network library
  - Additional ad network adapter for Admob (maybe contained in network library)